# What is a .s12 file (bios related)

Tags: bios

After launching the hp bios updater utility you will have the option to save the bios rom somewhere on the system drive, and it would create 2 files, the .bin file and an additional .s12 that makes me think my life choices. The weird thing is that if I extract the executable of the utility I can find the .bin file but there's not a single trace of that .s12 file.

```
04/29/2021  02:26 PM        16,777,216 085FA.bin
04/29/2021  02:26 PM               256 085FA.s12
```

Is it just a signature? What does it stands for? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Open it with a text editor... What is in it? It's only 256 bytes, it can't be much

Comment: I tried that before, it's encrypted.

Comment: typically there is a .bin, .s12, and .sig for HP BIOS... Not sure why you would only have two.

Comment: I believe the .s12 file is a signature for the bin, so its integrity can be verified before flash. There seem to be lots of vague references to it online, but its notable that many HP bioses don;t appear to ship a .sig file (sometimes its there, sometimes not), but they all appear to ship .s12 or .s14 files. I wonder if those numbers have any relationship to PKCS #12 or #14 specs for storing certificates and related information.

Comment: so when you say the file is "encrypted", can you describe what it looks like? is it a continuous string of alpha numeric characters (and does it end in = or == or another special character), or is it a bunch of weird characters like NUL or strange symbols with a bunch of whitespace?

Comment: It's not binary, neither hex, there are all types of characters mostly chinese, so typical encryption.

Answer (score 0):

The .s12 is the signature file of the .bin file [(see source and guide)](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/UEFI-Update/m-p/6626798/highlight/true#M525702).
You need them both to apply the HP BIOS image.
The .s12 file is a binary file, so it looks like an encrypted file.